# MenuItem order programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I am adding multiple menu items into a MenuItem control. The MenuItem control is created in the xaml, but it's empty. I use

```
MenuItem subMenuItem = new MenuItem();
subMenuItem.Header = "sub item 1";
MenuItemGroupA.Items.Insert( 0, subMenuItem);
```

to add sub menu items to it. This works fine. I want to, however, control the order of those sub menu items I added to the MenuItem, not by their names, nor by the order they are added. I tried to change the first argument to some other numbers. It seems to me that if I use anything that is greater than 0, the sub item is not added.

Any suggestions?

[Edit to add more details]

The code is in a function and is called several times, depends on the number of specific DLLs in a folder. For example, if there are 3 DLLs that I am looking for in that folder, I query their names and get Apple, Banana, Cherry. But I want the menu to show up like: Cherry, Apple, and Banana. I tried to create a dictionary like {{"Apple", 1}, {"Banana", 2}, {"Cherry", 3}} but don't even whether know this is useful.

Comment: _Any suggestions?_ Yes, give an example of how you want to construct a menu of 2+ items and how it should look. The simple answer is `Items.Add(subMenuItem);`

Comment: After the Edit: We still don't know why/how Cherry should come before Apple. Is this fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions.aspx) Property.

You can make the items sort by any property, for example the Tag property as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/55901f9f-fbe8-437a-9311-50e1bf8be6e5/menuitem-like-the-sort-menuitem-in-firefox-3s-organize-bookmarks-)